# Add '*' to the label of input fields with the 'required' attribute with CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am wondering if there is a way using only CSS to add an asterisk to a `label` element when the label's `for` attribute is for an `input` element with a `required` html attribute. Alternatively, we could use logic around if the `label` is directly followed by an `input` element which has the `required` attribute.

What does work is something like this:

```css
input[required] + label:after {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input for="name" type="text" required />
    <label id="name">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input for="age" type="text" />
    <label id="age">Age</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

But what I'm talking about is if the `label` and `input` are swapped around like the example below, which is more common. The CSS sibling selector `+` doesn't work for this case. Is there any way to do some like above when the `label` element is first and the `input` is second?

```css
/* ??? */
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input id="age" type="text" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: So label + input[required]:before doesn't work?

Comment: It's not really what I'm looking for. If the label and input elements were `display:block;` so they were on seperate lines, this wouldn't work. I like where your coming from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you keep old html and use css flex to order position

```css
input[required] + label:after {
 content: '*';
 color: red;
  }
  div {
   display: flex;
   text-align: center;
   align-items: flex-start;
  }
  div input {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
 order: 2;
  }
  div label {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
 order: 1;
  }
```

```html
<form>
        <div>
          <input for="name" type="text" required />
          <label id="name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input for="age" type="text" />
          <label id="age">Age</label>
        </div>
      </form>
```

See the [codepen](https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/wmYyMa)

Comment: Nice solution. I am using a similar method but instead I create an container and use   display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; to have the label and input element switch places.

Comment: Did you accidentally invert the "for" and "id" labels of the tags in your example? Isn't the label the one supposed to have the "for" while the input has the "id"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float` for label to positining label at left like below:

```css
label {
  float: left;
}

input[required] + label:after {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input for="name" type="text" required />
    <label id="name">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input for="age" type="text" />
    <label id="age">Age</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for CSS to "render backwards" the way you want it too (not without SASS/SCSS).

One solution would be to add a "required" class to the labels that correspond to required fields.

```
<style>
    label.required:after { content: '*';color:red; }
</style>

<form>
  <div>
    <label for="name" class="required">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input id="age" type="text" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Another option is the use of CSS3 Orders property, but the parent element would need to be set to "display:flex".

```
<style>
    div { display:-webkit-flex;display:flex; }
    div label { order:1; }
    div input { order:2; }
    div input[required] + label:after { content: '*';color:red; }
</style>

<form>
  <div>
    <input id="name" type="text" required />
    <label for="name">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="age" type="text" />
    <label for="age">Age</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

## EDIT 6/25/2019 SASS/SCSS Example

```
div {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    label {
        order:1;
    }
    input {
        order:2;
        &[required] + label:after {
            content: '*';color:red;
        }
    }
}
```

[More information about Parent Selectors in SCSS.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)

Comment: cool. what do you mean with not without SASS/SCSS? I'd love an answer using SASS/SCSS. but doesn't SASS/SCSS get transpiled into CSS anyway?

Comment: Also wondering how to do this with SCSS... Could you show us?

Comment: Jaxon, Yes, SCSS and SASS does get compiled into CSS. The beauty of SASS and SCSS is that it is much easier to maintain than a manually coded StyleSheet.

I will update my answer to reflect SASS/SCSS.